# How to change menu background of android Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

I have created a navigation drawer layout with menu in it. I wanted to change the background but it seems like I can't do that. I've tried solution given here like creating an drawable nav_bg.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/black_text"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@color/grey_55"/>
</selector>
```

and I use this drawable on the NavigationView layout xml :

```
app:itemBackground = "@drawable/nav_bg.xml"
```

but when I run the apps it just show me the @color/grey_55 color and it isn't changing when i pressed on it.

Comment: Where and how exactly have you used this drawable?

Comment: So what you really want to know, is how to set a different background color for the selected/active menu item?

Comment: please check my ans and ask me in case of any query

Comment: @azizbekian I've updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Easiest Way**

> Create .xml entry in drawable let say nav_checked_item_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/nav_checked_item" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

> create second drawable for checked item background representation let say nav_checked_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#6633b5e5"/>
</shape>
```

> Now add app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_checked_item_selector" to your NavigationView Layout.

Comment: Will you please put @color/black_text and @color/grey_55 and NavigationLayout code in your xml so I get some hints?

Comment: I tried to recreate my color xml into a drawable xml like yours and now it's working. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

In your NavigationView add :

```
app:itemIconTint="@color/menu_text_color"
app:itemTextColor="@color/menu_text_color"
app:itemBackground="@drawable/menu_background_color`"
```

In menu_background_color.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"android:state_checked="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="true"/>
 </selector>
```

In menu_text_color.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:color="@color/black" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

Open  **styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
   <item   name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/drawer_list_selector
   </item>
</style>
```

**2. Under res/drawable folder create **drawer_list_selector.xml** file**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"android:drawable="@drawable/light_gray_color"/>
    <item android:state_activated="true"android:drawable="@drawable/red_color"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

**3.Under res/drawable create red_color.xml / light_gray_color.xml (or any other name) and add your desired Hex color:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <solid android:color="#C8FF0000"/>
</shape>
```

**4- Open your project AndroidManifest.xml and add android:theme tag (if not exist)**

```
<application
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```